# Conditional Mean/Variance Help

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, variance

> Suppose you are deciding between three different transportation options, each with an average traveling time of $\mu_j$ hours and a standard deviation $\sigma_j$ hours. You randomly choose between the three options with equal probabilities. Let $T$ be the length of your trip. $\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$Find $\operatorname E(T)$ and $\Var(T)$.

So, your expected travel time is simply $\operatorname E(T) = (\mu_1 + \mu_2 + \mu_3) \cdot \frac{1}{3}.$
However, I'm a bit stuck on finding the variance. I understand you use the following formula, but don't know the interior values: $\Var(T) = \operatorname E(\Var(T\mid j)) + \Var(\operatorname E(T\mid j))$.

$\Var(T\mid j)$, I believe, should be $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_3^2$, but am stuck moving forward. any help?

Comment: Why do you write $\mu$ and then the subscript $_j$ between separate pairs of dollar signs rather than just one? That and some other aspects of your way of using MathJax add strange complications and give inferior results.

Answer (score 0):

Here, let $J$ be the random choice of transportation. Then, $\text{Var}(T \mid J)$ and $E[T \mid J]$ represent the variance and expectation of $T$ *given* you have chosen the $J$th transportation option and thus ought to depend on the value of $J$.
Can you compute these two "interior" values?

> $E[T \mid J=j] = \mu_j$ and $\text{Var}(T \mid J=j) = \sigma_j^2$.

Then, $E[\text{Var}(T \mid J)]$ is easy to compute, since it is $\frac{1}{3} \text{Var}[T \mid J=1] + \frac{1}{3} \text{Var}[T \mid J=2] +\frac{1}{3} \text{Var}[T \mid J=3]$.

For the variance term, just think of how you would compute the variance of a random variable that takes the values $E[T \mid J=1]$, $E[T \mid J=2]$, $E[T \mid J=3]$ with equal probability.

Comment: When you refer to E[var(T|J)] = 1/3 $\frac{1}{3}$ ET|J = 1] + ... do you mean  $\frac{1}{3}$ E[var(T|J=1)]?

Comment: @StephF Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Var(T)=E(T^2)-(E(T))^2$ you already have $E(T)$, now note that $E(T^2)=E(E(T^2/j))$.

Use the fact that $E(T^2/j)=Var(T/j)+(E(T/j))^2$ and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle J = \begin{cases} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 & \text{each with probability } 1/3. \\ \mu_3 \end{cases}$

Then $\begin{cases} \operatorname{var(T\mid J=\mu_1)} = \sigma_1, \\ \operatorname{var(T\mid J=\mu_2)} = \sigma_2, \\ \operatorname{var(T\mid J=\mu_3)} = \sigma_3.  \end{cases}$

These each happen with probability $1/3,$ so $\operatorname{E}(T\mid J) = \begin{cases} \mu_1, \\ \mu_2, & \text{each with probability }1/3. \\  \mu_3. \end{cases}$

I.e. $\operatorname{E}(T\mid J) = J.$

Therefore $\operatorname{var}(\operatorname E(T\mid J)) = \operatorname{var}(J).$

Then we have $\begin{cases} \operatorname{var}(T\mid J=\mu_1) = \sigma_1, \\ \operatorname{var}(T\mid J=\mu_3) = \sigma_2, \\ \operatorname{var}(T\mid J=\mu_3) = \sigma_3, \end{cases}$ and so $\operatorname{E}(\operatorname{var}( T\mid J)) = (\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+\sigma_3^2)/3.$

Thus we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(T) & = \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{var}(T\mid J)) + \operatorname{var}(\operatorname{E}(T\mid J)) \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+\sigma_3^2} 3 + \operatorname{var} (J).
\end{align}

The first term is the "unexplained" component of the variance. The second term is "explained" by the differences among $\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3.$